# 3 characters repeated NOT consecutively

Tags: html, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression in HTML pattern attribute so that my string has 4 characters, words and numbers only, but with no character repeated 3 or more times.

I've come up with this one, but it only checks for 3 consecutive characters, I need non-consecutively repeated also.

```
(?!.*([A-Za-z0-9])\1{2})[A-Za-z0-9]{4}
```

Also, string should be case insensitive, for example:

```
dadd - invalid,
dadD - also invalid,
dada - valid,
1121 - invalid,
1122 - valid
```

I couldn't find any answers online and I'm stuck at the moment.

Comment: Can you give some examples of valid and invalid strings?

Comment: Sure, Max1 - valid, MamM - invalid, 1211 - invalid, 1212 - valid.

Comment: [`^(?!.*(.)(?:.*\1){2})[A-Za-z0-9]{4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/Nj0qpL/1). You may remove the first `^` and last `$` since it is used in the HTML5 pattern attribute.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, this one checks for strings like dadd as invalid correctly, but I still have issues when there is a capital letter involved, for example dadD returns as valid while it should be invalid also.

Comment: @lupu51nfactumN778 Sorry, then you need to use custom validation as you cannot pass the `i` modifier inside the HTML5 pattern.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thanks, post an example if you can please. I edited the original question to clarify that strings should be case insensitive. S.Jovan Thanks, I am still having issue with strings like daad - returning invalid when I try `(?:([a-z0-9])(?!\1)){4}`

Comment: I do not think it is possible. Use a workaround, check the value on blur event, and use custom logic to guide the user.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, HTML form validation can be done by JavaScript.

If the input in the form field (`fname`) does not meet the regex pattern, the function alerts a message, and returns false, to prevent the form from being submitted:

```js
function validateForm() {
    var str = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    const regex = /^(?!.*(.)(?:.*\1){2})[a-z0-9]{4}$/i;
  let m;
    if ((m = regex.exec(str)) == null) {
    alert("Use the following format: 4 characters, words and numbers only, but with no character repeated 3 or more times.");
   return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```